# Get the transformed dataframe from a Pipeline

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a pipeline that includes `VectorAssembler`, `StringIndexer` and `KMeans` stages as shown below:

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(string_indexer :+ assembler :+ kmeans)
```

Assume that the pipeline is fitted using the following command:

```
val model = pipeline.fit(df)
```

How can I access the dataframe `df` that has been used by `KMeans` once the df has been transformed using `StringIndexer` and `VectorAssembler`? (i.e. I want the final dataframe produced by `StringIndexer` and `VectorAssembler`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `transform` method to transform DataFrame with your model:

```
val newDF = model.transform(df)
```

New DataFrame, newDF, will have all columns that were produced in your code